# How do i Hide particular column showfilterrow in Jqx grid

Tags: jqxgrid

Actually im working on Jqx Grid. I have a requirement of show filter row (Quick search) . I need to apply it only to a single column but its applying to all the columns i need to Hide the columns which i dont require . Can any one Help me out ? Here is the Code which i had applied :

width:'100%',
                                height:345,
                                source: dataAdapter,
                                showfilterrow: true,
                                groupable: true,
                                sortable: true,
                                showaggregates: true,
                                altrows: true,
                                autorowheight: true,
                                filterable: true,
                                pageable: true,
                                columnsresize: true,
                                columns: [ 
{ text: 'Name',columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'textbox',datafield: 'projectName', width:'20%'},

{ text: 'Est.StartDate',columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'textbox', datafield: 'estStartDate', width: '20%' },

{ text: 'Est.EndDate',columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'textbox', datafield: 'estEndDate', width: '20%' },

{ text: 'Status',columntype: 'textbox', filtertype: 'textbox', datafield: 'status', width: '20%' },

{ text: 'Attachments', datafield: 'attachments',search: false,width: '20%' },

{ text: 'Action', width: 100,cellsalign: 'center' }

Answer (score 0):

for the columns you don't want to show a filter control, add the property

```
filterable: false
```